# AWS Policy Generator giving error with S3 ARN: "Resource field is not valid. You must enter a valid ARN."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I go to create new s3 policy I have the issue below:

[image: AWS Policy Generator]

I can't add a new statement with my bucket name: `lam.nguyen-test`

[image: S3 Bucket]

```
my Principle : *
 
ARN generator : arn:aws:s3:::lam.nguyen-test/*
```

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your situation. It would appear that the Policy Generator is not correctly recognising ARNs. As a workaround, you can enter `*` and then fix the ARN in the policy after it is generated.

Comment: Thank John Rotenstein
But I don't understand your answer. Could you help me clear it. please

Comment: There appears to be a bug in the Policy Generator (not your fault). Use `*` for now, but change it to your full ARN when you paste the text into the Bucket Policy.